# Can you please explain how the terminal prompt works?

Tags: macos, terminal

I've got a question about the prompt in Mac's Terminal.
I opened Terminal and was installing GIT. I don't know anything about Unix or how to use Terminal, so please forgive my ignorance. (I know that Terminal is very powerful, though. And it's easy to screw things up!)

The prompt reads as follows:

```
Macintosh-2:~ myname$
```

What does the `Macintosh-2` mean? I've never seen this in front of a Terminal prompt.

Do you think that my mac is okay? What happened to the standard prompt?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Mac. The "background" story I removed (edits under review) because they don't apply here. The prompt is the standard OS X prompt. See Matteo's answer for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's your computer hostname. You can see and edit the value in "System Preferences -> Sharing -> Computer Name".

The prompt of the default shell (bash) can be changed by overriding the `PS1` environment value.

```
# will show >
export PS1='>'

# will show the hostname followed by a space and >
export PS1='\s >'
```

These values are entered in a file called `.bash_profile` located in the root of your home directory (e.g., `/Users/yourname/` or `~/`). The period before the file name effectively hides it. You can read more about unix hidden files [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory).

You can see the complete list of special characters (e.g., `\s`) in the [manual page of bash](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) (your default shell).

Type `man bash` in the terminal and scroll down to the `PROMPTING` section. And if you'd like to unlock their potential, head on over to [Prompt Magic](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/) and play around.

Comment: Excellent answer Matteo! I added an edit on where they can enter those values.

Comment: @Matteo, thank you for the excellent answer. Have you ever heard of Mac OSX changing a machine's hostname for some reason? Or a virus/malware doing so? Is it something to worry about or am I over-thinking this? Thank you!

Comment: @Laxmidi: it depends, hostname can be automatically changed depending on your network location. I also some System updates add a "-2" to my default host name and never understood why.

Comment: @Matteo, Cool. If its happened to others, then it probably isn't something to worry about. Thanks so much.

Comment: It's recommended that you place most customizations in ~/.bashrc and have ~/.bash_profile run ~/.bashrc, so that your customizations apply to both login and non-login shells alike.

Comment: @Matteo The system will automatically edit its hostname to make it unique if there's already a machine with that hostname on the local network. I'm not sure why that might happen in the context of an OS update, but I suppose it might be because there's a “ghost” of your computer still on the network for some reason.